# Javascript - move box from current position ( testimonial slider )

Tags: javascript, css, slider, translate, testimonials

I can't figured out how to move the boxes `back and forth`.

I can move from `left to right`, but if i try from `right to left` it goes crazy.

Here you have the [code](https://gist.github.com/grecdev/e44f22f067428ada54914705e7f4098d)

Here you have the [live example](https://codepen.io/grecdev/pen/PoYrWBr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the output of the `box.style.transform.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')`.

It returned the only the positive number e.g: `100px` even if the property value is: `translateX(-100px)`.

The solution was to get the negative value aswell. All i need to do was to change the `regex statement`.

SOLUTION: `box.style.transform.replace(/[^-\d]/g, '')`.

EXPLANATION: Replace all characters that are NOT `-` or `number / digit`.

[Code](https://gist.github.com/grecdev/e44f22f067428ada54914705e7f4098d) and [live example](https://codepen.io/grecdev/full/PoYrWBr) updated.